# R Shiny - unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbGetQuery’

Tags: r, sqlite, shiny

Why do I keep getting this error below,

> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbGetQuery’ for
>   signature ‘"SQLiteConnection", "data.frame"’

for,

```
  # Fetch all site names.
  siteQuery <- dbGetQuery(DB, "SELECT nid, title, description 
                     FROM nodes 
                     WHERE datatype = 'speck' 
                     AND visible = '1'
                     AND nid = 'SITE'
                     ")

  # Match the pattern and replace it.
  siteQuery <- sub("SITE", as.character(site1), siteQuery)

  # Store the result in data.
  siteData = dbGetQuery(DB, siteQuery)
```

Is it an error in my sqlite query or in my R script? Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Because, as the error message says, siteQuery is a data frame, not a string containing SQL.

Comment: Please use query parameters; don't use string manipulation to insert data into a query. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: can you show me same examples please...?

Answer (score -2):

```
  # Fetch a site.
  siteQuery <- "SELECT nid, title, description 
            FROM nodes 
            WHERE datatype = 'speck' 
            AND visible = '1'
            AND nid = 'SITE'
            "

  # Match the pattern and replace it.
  siteQuery <- sub("SITE", as.character(site1), siteQuery)

  # Store the result in data.
  siteData = dbGetQuery(DB, siteQuery)
```